# Cumulative Row percentage in pivot table Excel

Tags: excel, pivot-table, percentage, cumulative-sum

I would like to summarise the data using a cumulative row percentage while the row is aggregated by year-month. I posted a screenshot of the "raw data" and the aggregated data below. So in the second screenshot I would like to see the cumulative row-percentage per year/month.

I tried the "value as" options, but didn't find anything that worked.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

To display running percentage totals, you normally just right click on the Values field, select *Show Values As*, then choose *% Running Total In*.